# Cumsum Python Dataframe - until previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I would replicate this Excel formula:

```
=SUMIFS($AD$6:AD6;$D$6:D6;D7)
```

I want obtain a cumulative result until previous row

```
ID = [1,1,1,2,2]
$ = [10,10,10,10,10]
```

Result = `[nan,10,20,nan,10]`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) or [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,1,1,2,2],
    '$': [10,10,10,10,10]
    })

df['new'] = df.groupby('ID')['$'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
#alternative
#df['new'] = df.groupby('ID')['$'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
print (df)
   ID   $   new
0   1  10   NaN
1   1  10  10.0
2   1  10  20.0
3   2  10   NaN
4   2  10  10.0
```

Comment: I ran into a performance issue while using `np.where`, if you are free, Can you please join this [ROOM](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217594/data-science-discussions)?